# How to save a File locally (without a Sandbox) with MKS CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, mks-integrity

I want to save different revisions of a file from MKS Integrity using the Command Line Interface. The aim is to save these two files locally and use a script I wrote to compare them.

When I check the member history I can double click on the Revision Number and the file opens up in the chosen Editor. This file is saved in the TEMP Folder locally.

How can I do it using the command line arguments. Till now I have found the ***si edit*** command. This opens the file locally and creates a copy in the TEMP Folder but with a weird name.

If someone could help me with a better command that is available and I have overlooked in the documentation or if someone could tell me how the name is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `projectco` command.

```
si projectco --nolock --project=<project id> --targetFile=<outputfile> <projectmember>
```

Answer (score -1):

To clarify that answer, you should add quotes for project, outputfile and projectmember.

si projectco --nolock --project="" --targetFile="" ""